# Sum values of array by key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to find array values by key and sum this values if key exists in other array. I tried to different combination but I havent a good idea.

```
array(2) {
      ["www.test.pl"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["category"]=>
        array(3) {

        }
        ["category2"]=>
        array(3) {

        }
      }
      ["www.test2.pl"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["category"]=>
        array(3) {

        }
        ["category2"]=>
        array(3) {

        }
        ["category3"]=>
        array(3) {

        }
      }
    }
```

I need to compare keys -"category", "category2" Of every URL ... and sum values if I have keys in both array of URLs.

I tries to do this in this example
[link to compare array code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e6356680e7013554793422f0fbd48bf81a0ee39)

Comment: What's the other array structure?

Comment: _I need to compare "category", "category2" ... and sum values..._ What is stopping you from doing that? Any errors?

Comment: I need to foreach in array where I have urls and compare keys if I find key for example (category) in "www.test.pl" and "www.test2.pl" then I need to sum clicks, impressions and ctr for this key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can summ values in ne array:

```
// $arr1 - starting array
$arr2 = [];

foreach ($arr1 as $arr){
    foreach ($arr as $arKey => $arVal) {
        if (isset($arr2[$arKey])) {
            $arr2[$arKey]['clicks'] += $arVal['clicks'];
            $arr2[$arKey]['impressions'] += $arVal['impressions'];
            $arr2[$arKey]['ctr'] += $arVal['ctr'];
        } else {
            $arr2[] = [
               'clicks' => $arVal['clicks'],
               'impressions' => $arVal['impressions'],
               'ctr' => $arVal['ctr'],
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it is what you want to do

Comment: Can You see that I have array in array there? This is array of URL. Every URL can Have array of arrays. I need to foreach in array where I have urls and compare keys if I find key for example (category) in "www.test.pl" and "www.test2.pl" then I need to sum clicks, impressions and ctr for this key

Comment: I added one more loop foreach

Comment: Not work like I want. I tried this option before You say me. Look my result array.. Your result return me gigantic array with repeated values becouse this is loop in loop. I need sum if keys like "category" I have in both array and not sum if I haven't. Now Result is repeated

Comment: Oh yes thanks it works like I have wanted when You have added next foreach but this works like sorting in new array. I need to have information if $arKey is in next loop of first foreach($arr1 as $arr). Now I dont know how many times $arKey occurred in arr1. I need to have this information in every loop of second foreach. I think about this and I havent idea how I can modify Your example now

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(isset($array2[$key])){
         $sum = $array2[$key]+$value;   
    }
}
```